# Dynamic URL MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a new website in MVC and since I am new with MVC I have a small problem:

I have several types of pages, And I take them out of the data base

My Question is how do I get the application to decide which controller & view to go
For example I have a menu that I take from the database and there are pages name:
about and products.

www.site.com/about  - is a text page type 
And
www.site.com/products - is a Product type Page

thanks

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand what you're asking. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The [MVC SiteMap provider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) can do this for you.